# Is any way to insert text box in python-docx?

Tags: python, textbox, docx, python-docx

I have a predefined DOCX document that contains text boxes. I want to update the text within these text boxes, or if someone suggests, replace the text box with my desired content. Is it possible to achieve this using python-docx?

First I think i should remove using paragraph.text but it ot works.